# Return one value from Json object

Tags: java, json, rest

Below is the json response I got through rest response. I want to print only the name in Json format:
For example:
{
name: "abcd"
}

This is the response I get:

```
{
id: 378
name: "abcd"
street: "street name"
house no: "200"
zip code: "22998"
City: "New York"
City: "New York"
Country: "USA"
}
```

Comment: What language you are using for JSON paersing Please post the code

Comment: Post the code that you have tried

Comment: @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })

Comment: if i use jsonobj.getName(); it print just the abcd but i want the name: "abcd"

Comment: I just answered the try it

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

If You are using Java try this. You can use `JSONObject` class for parse the json and get `name` value from it.

```
JSONObject jsononj= new JSONObject(json_string); // Your json string here
String name = jsonobj.optString("name");
System.out.println(name);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this, its working

```
public class JsonRead{

public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    String data="{id: 378,name:\"abcd\",street:\"street name\",house no: \"200\",zip code: \"22998\",City: \"New York\",City: \"New York\",Country: \"USA\"}";
    JSONObject parse = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONObject newData=new JSONObject();
    System.out.println("value of name::::  "+parse.get("name"));
    newData.put("name", parse.get("name"));
    System.out.println("In JSon Format:::::"+newData.toString());

}
}
```

> **Output:**
>
> value of name::::  abcd
>
> New Json:::::{"name":"abcd"}

Hope this helps you with your problem...!!!!!!